# Calling API and passing data to another component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-redux-form

I am working on react application in which I need to call the API with press of a button and the API response should be transferred to the second component along with displaying the content of second component. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to hold the fetched data inside `state` and pass it as a `property` to a child component which is conditionally rendered.

Function Components

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react'

class ParentComponent {
  state = {
   data: undefined
}
  const handleClick = async () => {
    //fetchData
this.setState({data: fetchedData})
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click me </button>
      {this.state.data && <Child data={this.state.data} />}
    </div>
  );
};

const Child = (props) => {
  return (
    //render data
    <div>{props.data}</div>
  );
};
```

Class Components

```js
import React from "react";

class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: undefined,
  };
  handleClick = async () => {
    //fetchData
    this.setState({ data: fetchedData });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click me </button>
        {this.state.data && <Child data={this.state.data} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      //render data
      <div>{this.props.data}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How to use it in a class ?

Comment: I edited the answer for usage with classes. Maybe you should look into the getting started doc pages from the official [react page](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html).

Comment: Instead of loading the data of child component, I want to be redirected to that component with the response data. Help is much appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Check out [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) for routing inside a react app. Routes are still just "components", so you can either pass data to them or information with which they can fetch data themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very specific. If you want to make an api call there are a lot of tutorials online.
For example: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html

On having an event in one component populate data in another component you should handle this by keeping the data in the parent component that contains both the button component and the display component.

Comment: So, basically with the press of a button an API call is being made; there is some response of the API which needs to be passed to second component and also I need to load that second component, basically redirect.